# It is helpful to normalize target variables for a regression neural network?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, normalization

It is customary to normalize feature variables and this normally does increase the performance of a neural network in particular a CNN. I was wondering if normalizing the target could also help increase performance? I did not notice an increase in performance with the data set I am using at the moment but was curious if anyone has tried in the past. Of course the normalization happens only on the training data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason for normalising the inputs is to make gradient descent more stable, as gradients spend more time in a comfortable region with meaningful updates and less neurons 'die' during trainings - getting stuck at one of the tails of e.g. the sigmoid non-linearity.

Normalising the output distribution is perhaps not the best idea, as you are by definition altering the defition of the target. This means you are essentially predicting a distribution that doesn't mirror your real-world target (at least without some reverse non-linear transforms later on).

On this you could do would be to *scale* the target, instead of normalising. The shape of the distribution should remain almost identical (thinking about the *shape* of the distribution), but the values themselves might be more easily attainable and therefore faster to optimise for; they are all closer in magnitude to the gradients that are being computed.